# How to print the retain count of an object?

Tags: objective-c, nslog, retaincount

I am trying to print out the retain count of an object in the terminal using NSLog. Here is my  code:

```
NSNumber *myInt=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 100];
NSLog(@"myInt retain count=%d",[myInt retainCount]);
```

The result should be 1 but what I have got at the terminal is -1. I tried to use %u instead of  %d and ended up getting 4294967295 as result. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: `retainCount` is useless.  Don't call it.  What you are seeing is an implementation detail;  the `NSNumber` returned is probably a *tagged pointer* and, thus, there is no allocation and nothing to retain.

Comment: So all the books talking about returnCount functionality are simply bullshitting then?

Comment: They may be misguided rather than bullshitting, but they're inaccurate.

Comment: Yup; any book that discusses retainCount as if it were useful is suspect. An object's retainCount only makes sense when there is no threading, no autorelease, no passes through system APIs, and you aren't subclassing a framework class, among other things.  http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before @bbum gets here I get to say this:

**Don't rely on `-retainCount` in your code**

It doesn't give you answers you expect. It turns out that the answer -1 is correct here, the fact that you don't think it's correct is because the framework is doing something you don't know about behind your back. Use automatic reference counting (ARC), or if you must use manual retain/release just follow the memory management guidelines without using the `-retainCount` method.

Comment: My code is based on some old examples. Does it mean that Apple has changed Objective-C at some point so retainCount no longer behaves as it used to do?

Comment: No; retainCount was never reliable except in very limited circumstances.

Comment: Is ARC going to return what retainCount should return? What about retain then? Does it also misbehave?

Comment: ARC doesn't let you call retainCount _or_ retain. You don't know what retainCount is doing, stop relying on its results.

Comment: So how to return the reference count then? ARC?

Comment: Don't. You don't know what it means.